# How to find a file and its path in some nested subdirectory from a Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

I tried this in CMD :

```
DIR /S DIRECTORY | FIND /I "FILENAME"
```

; but this only shows whether the file is found or not ; the output does not contain the Path.

One way is to use `EXPLORER` , but I want to use `CMD`.

Another way is `DIR /S | MORE`, manually looking for the file. Yet another way is to get the full output of `DIR /s` and then search this text for filename, but these methods have too many issues like slowness or too much scrolling or too manual.

I am looking for a simple way to execute a built-in command and find the file with Path.

[[ While typing this question, I found a solution which I will add, for future visitors with the same question; but I would also be happy to see if others have a better solution ]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was surprisingly easy, but I was not aware of it till now:

```
DIR /S FILENAME DIRECTORY
```

will search for FILENAME (even with wildcards) in DIRECTORY and show matching files with the PATH.
I would be happy to know if there are better solutions.